# Returning entity only from LUIS

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

What if I just want to return an entity from text sent to LUIS from BotFramework But it is not trigged by any intent?  For example my bot has already asked the user to specify a time range eg((Monday at 3pm to Monday at 9pm) and I just want to send this to get a builtin.datetimeV2.datetimerange back?  I currently am just sending it to LuisIntent("None")  and it works but this feels wrong.  Should I be doing this differently?

Answer (score 0):

Labeling your entities with an intent of "None" is fine.

Is this for a LUIS call inside of a dialog? Or is this for a LUIS call that will initiate a dialog?

Comment: Thank you.  No it is just inside a dialog.  In fact I will likely re use the same call inside multiple dialogs.  Should I have this in it's own app just for this?

Comment: Are you using the C# SDK or the Node SDK? I would say yes for both, though I'm not familiar enough with the C# SDK to recommend how to do so.

Comment: Yes C#.  It definitely works it just feels like a bad pattern.

Comment: Sorry about that, we might be thinking of different things. When you said app, I was thinking of doing a simple REST call to LUIS. E.g. your chatbot hitting the LUIS endpoint and then parsing the results . An example of this in Node would just be using a Promise with an async call  inside of a dialog

Comment: In Node you would use a module to set up said REST call and assign it to a helper function which could be called inside of any dialog; your chatbot would parse the results from LUIS inside of the waterfall. That's what I was actually thinking of in my agreement with you

Answer (score 0):

Like @Steven G mentioned, you can just call LUIS directly, and parse the json result.

```
public class LUISRestService
{
    public static async Task<string> GetLuisResult(string searchFor)
    {
        string LUISEndpoint = $"https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/[YOURLUSAPPID]?subscription-key=[YOURSUBSCRIPTIONKEY]&timezoneOffset=0&verbose=true&q={searchFor}";
        string result = "";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(LUISEndpoint);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(LUISEndpoint);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```